# JOIN showing duplicate results? :/

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have some join's and I am retrieving "tags" associated with a piece of content. 
I get my tags bag fine but they are duplicated like 6-7 times each.

```
SELECT                                                                      

  users.userName,                                                           
  usersProfiles.avatarUrl,                                                  
  usersProfiles.gender,                                                     

  GROUP_CONCAT(contentComments.message SEPARATOR ', ') AS comments,          

  c.*,                                                                      

  GROUP_CONCAT(tagWords.tagWord SEPARATOR ', ') AS tags,                    

  (SELECT COUNT(contentId) FROM platform.contentLikes    WHERE contentId = 1213) as feedBackLikes                                                             

FROM platform.contents c                                                   

INNER JOIN platform.users ON users.userId = c.userId                       
INNER JOIN platform.usersProfiles ON usersProfiles.userId = c.userId       
INNER JOIN platform.contentTags ON contentTags.contentId = c.contentId     
INNER JOIN platform.tagWords ON contentTags.tagId = tagWords.tagId         
INNER JOIN platform.contentComments ON contentComments.contentId = c.contentId                                                                            

WHERE c.contentTitle = :contentTitle AND c.userId = :userId
```

Any tips or suggestions as to why this happens and if it is wrong, how would I go about doing it the right way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the INNER JOIN's is not retrieving a unique record but several. Try commenting the INNER JOIN's and uncommenting them one by one to see which one it is.

**Update:** Sorry, jumping to conclusions. Ignacio is right, there should be a GROUP BY.